# Pergunta urgente Python

Tags: python

Sabendo o número da linha específica em um arquivo TXT, como eu faço para converter todo o texto dessa linha em uma variável do tipo String?

Por exemplo: eu tenho na linha 5 escrito : " Hello world"; e eu quero transformar o "Hello World" em uma variável do tipo String sabendo somente o número da linha.

Comment: Olá, Pierre. Fechamos sua pergunta anteriormente e esclareci nos comentários o que deveria ser feito para melhorar a mesma. Ao invés de duplicar a pergunta, você deve **[editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/502795/edit) a mesma e fornecer um [mcve]**. Se você não entendeu como o site funciona e como deve perguntar aqui, sugiro uma leitura na [help].